# Зачем нужны && и & после метода в классе? C++

Tags: c++, классы

Наткнулся на код, где в конце методов были && и &. Нечто подобное:

```
      class Quote {            
       public:     
           virtual Quote* clone() const & {return new Quote(*this);}            
           virtual Quote* clone() &&            
            {return new Quote(std::move(*this));}            
           // другие члены как прежде             
      };            

      class Bulk_quote : public Quote {            
           Bulk_quote* clone() const & {return new Bulk_quote(*this);}            
           Bulk_quote* clone() &&            
            {return new Bulk_quote(std::move(*this));}            
           // другие члены, как прежде             
      };
```

Что делают символы & и && ПОСЛЕ метода? (Зачем они нужны в параметрах я знаю). Где можно почитать о таком их использовании и как это называется?

Comment: [на английском](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions), раздел ref-qualified member functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это перегрузка по вызову функций для lvalue (&) и rvalue (&&). Называется reference-qualified member functions.

То есть, если написать

```
Quote q;
q.clone();
```

будет вызвано clone  с одним &, потому что q это lvalue.

А вот так

```
Quote().clone();
```

То будет вызван второй вариант.

Зачем это нужно? очевидно, что в  некоторых случаях второй вариант может приводить к утечками и хотелось бы избежать и это можно сделать

```
virtual Quote* clone() const & {return new Quote(*this);}            
virtual Quote* clone() &&  = delete;
```

и второй вариант (`Quote().clone();`) не будет компилироваться

почитать больше https://habr.com/ru/post/216783/

Comment: То есть я правильно понял, что & - этот метод будет компилироваться только если экземпляр класса - l-value, а && если r-value?

Comment: только не экземпляр класса, а выражение. Да, это очень-очень похоже, но все таки, это чуточку разные вещи.

Comment: Плюс `const &` будет вызываться и на rvalue тоже, но с меньшим приоритетом чем `&&`.

Comment: За необернутый вызов `new` надо копчик массировать... Еще одно применение: геттеры, которые для rvalue автоматически мувают поле ([пример](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*)).

Comment: всякое бывает. но меня функции с &&=delete несколько раз хорошо выручали - компилятор сразу - ай-яй-яй.